# If someone lacks the will to live, can there still be anything he is willing to pursue?

Tags: life, meaning-of-life

After reading some posts such as [What is the motivation of all individuals to stay alive?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/75994/what-is-the-motivation-of-all-individuals-to-stay-alive) and [Why care for anything in life?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/97054/why-care-for-anything-in-life) , we'd like to pose a question in a different (perhaps more accurate) way:

> If someone lacks the will to live, can there still be anything he is willing to pursue?

For example, personal growth is one of the common options people pursue.
However, it remains doubted especially when someone even lacks the will to live.

(Note: The pitfall of short-term pleasure is excluded here. Some related discussion can be found in:
[3](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/97056/47770)
[4](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/50744/why-cant-we-or-why-shouldnt-we-seek-the-things-that-give-us-direct-pleasure/50745#50745))

Comment: A question worth asking.

Comment: Isn't the lack of the will to live more about very subjective emotional states and less about purpose? In that sense the question seems inapplicable. The question also implies all or nothing rather than a graduated weighting between a the will to tolerate things and purpose. For example, just because you lack the will to get out of bed in the morning to attend classes doesn't mean you have no desire to work to become a doctor.

Comment: Will to live is simply the nature of human being's endeavor to persist the said being itself, and pursue is nothing else but a way to persist one's interest which ultimately is to persist oneself, otherwise one can always let others pursue the said interest...

Comment: It could be that the loss of will to live is the result of an inability to continue to pursue something, in which case they would still be *willing* to pursue it, just not have the means to do so.

Comment: do you mean, if you have aims then do you have the will (to life)? dunno, but have been troubled by the inverse before

Comment: How about kamikaze, suicide bombers, soldiers who stay to delay the fall of a position they know to be untenable? Exemples can be found of people who are resolute to die while pursuing something. One could argue that, since they intent on staying alive until their goal is accomplished they still have some "will to live". At the very least it shows we need to define the term "will to live" more carefully.

Answer (score -1):

> If someone lacks the will to live, can there still be anything he is
> willing to pursue?

**Freedom**.